# Joint queries through foreign key

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

I have the following two models: `File` and `Session`, and a single session could have many File objects (one-to-many).

```
type Session struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name            string       `json:"name,omitempty"`    
    IsCurrent       bool         `json:"is_current"`
    Files     []File `gorm:"foreignkey:SessionID" json:"files"`
}

type File struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    FileType    string `json:"file_type"`
    ParentName  string `json:"parent_name"`
    SessionID   uint   `json:"session_id"`
}
```

I'd like to get all the files associated to the session that has `IsCurrent = true`

I wrote the following raw SQL query that seems to work fine, but I'd like to know if there's any way to do a similar query int he [Gorm](http://doc.gorm.io/advanced.html#compose-primary-key) way.

> err = db.Raw("SELECT * FROM files, sessions WHERE files.session_id == sessions.id AND sessions.is_current = ?", true).Scan(&fileObjects).Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TonyGW the key is using a combination of `Preload` and `Where` in your Gorm call.

```
currentSession := &Session{}

err := db.Model(&Session{}).Preload("Files").Where(&Session{IsCurrent: true}).Find(&currentSession).Error
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println("Error:", err)
}

fmt.Printf("%+v\n", currentSession)
```

**FYI**

There are a number of ways you can structure the `Where` query. Eg,

```
db.Model(&Session{}).Preload("Files").Where("is_current = ?", true).Find(&currentSession)
```

and also using a map to build up multiple `Where` conditions,

```
db.Model(&Session{}).Preload("Files").Where(map[string]interface{}{
  "is_current": true,
  "something_else": "value",
}).Find(&currentSession)
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
db.Where("is_current = ?", true).Model(&session).Related(&session.Files)
```